# How can I write a generic Python 2.2 function that returns a list of unset parameters?

Tags: python, jython

I have a function with many input parameters, and I need a function that will return a list of parameter names (not values) for each parameter whose value is '' or None

Normally I'd throw an exception in such a method.  If anyone wants to crack the problem by throwing an exception, that is fine.  I still have the requirement that the function return the list of parameter names.

To summarize

1. Return a list of parameter names for parameters that are unset
2. "unset" means the parameter's value is not empty string or None
3. Accept a single parameter: a single dimension list or dict
4. The list should contain the complete set of empty parameter names
5. I need it to be backward compatible with Python 2.2 and Jython
6. 2.2 is non-negotiable.  The code must run on legacy systems that we have no authority to upgrade.  Sucks to be us.
7. The parameters are not command line arguments, but parameters to a
   function.
8. The parameters are stored in individual variables, but I can manually put them into a dict if necessary.
9. Instead of returning a list of Python variable names, return a list of user-friendly descriptions for each empty variable.  Example:  "Database Name" vs "db_name".

Answers to questions raised:

1. What if an unknown parameter is encountered?  We don't care.  We create the list of parameters to validate and select only those which are mandatory by virtue of the system's logic.  Thus we'd never put an unknown parameter into the list of ones to validate
2. What about UI parameters that are not mandatory or which must be validated in other ways (int vs. string, etc)?  We would not put the non-mandatory params in the list we pass to the validation function.  For other more complex validations, we handle these individually, adhoc.  The reason this function seemed convenient is because empty parameters are the most common validation we do, and writing an `if not foo:` for each one gets tedious across functions, of which we have many.
3. Please explain """By nature of our platform""". Also """it arrives in individual variables""" ... individual variables in what namespace? And what does """(preprocessing)""" mean? – John Machin 2 days ago.  Answer:  The variables are in the global namespace.  We use code injection (similar to how a C preprocessor would substitute code for macro names, except we are substituting variable values for tags, similar to this:

   DATABASE_NAME = ^-^Put the variable the user entered for database name here^-^

which ends up like this after the preprocessor runs:

```
DATABASE_NAME = "DB1"
```

Here is a concrete example showing why a simple method throwing an exception would not work.  I have rewritten to use an exception rather than returning a value, by request:

```
def validate_parameters(params_map):
    """
    map is like {foo: "this is foo"}
    """
    missing_params_info = []
    for k,v in params_map.items():
        if not k:
            missing_params_info.append(v)
    if missing_params_info:
        raise TypeError('These parameters were unset: %s' % missing_params_info)

params = {}
params['foo'] = '1'
params['bar'] = '2'
params['empty'] = ''
params['empty2'] = ''
params['None'] = None
params_map = {
    params['foo']: 'this is foo',
    params['bar']: 'this is bar',
    params['empty']: 'this is empty',
    params['empty2']: 'this is empty2',
    params['None']: 'this is None',
}

print validate_parameters(params_map)


bash-3.00# python /var/tmp/ck.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/tmp/ck.py", line 26, in ?
    print validate_parameters(params_map)
  File "/var/tmp/ck.py", line 10, in validate_parameters
    raise TypeError('These parameters were unset: %s' % missing_params_info)
TypeError: These parameters were unset: ['this is empty2', 'this is None']
```

Two reasons it doesn't work for us: It only prints empty2, even though there is another empty parameter, "empty".  "empty" is overwritten by "empty2" because they use the same key in the map.

Second reason:  I need to get the list of descriptions into a variable at some point after running this function.  Maybe this is possible with exceptions, but I don't know how right now.

I've posted an answer that seems to solve all these problems, but is not ideal.  I marked the question answered, but will change that if someone posts a better answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Please define "validate".  Does it mean "has a value"?  Also, returning a "user-friendly descriptions" instead of a proper result is a horrible, horrible thing to do.  Perfectly awful.  Please rethink and clarify your requirements.  What's wrong with `func( **some_map )` as a way to pass an arbitrary mapping to a function as arguments?

Comment: Validate means that the value of the parameter is not '' or None.  It must past the test: "if foo:" with True.  I realize the description requirement is awful, but it is the result of having to link parameter values to user-facing fields on a UI.  Could you elaborate on func( **some_map )?  I don't understand.  I know this is a pointer to the map, but not sure how it would solve the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: To elaborate more on returning a "proper result", this would mean returning, for instance, a map containing the parameter itself and the description.  If the map is empty, success.  If it's not, we have our list of errors to report.

Comment: "Normally I'd throw an exception in such a method."  Good.  "I'd rather leave it to the caller to determine if the results warrant an exception or simply a warning."  What?  An exception **does** leave it to the caller to handle the exception, change it to a warning, or let the application crash.  An exception is **always** the right thing to do.  Please rethink your requirements.  Also.  Please don't add comments.  Please just update the question to be more clear.

Comment: What do you want to do if an *unknown* parameter name is supplied? Raise an exception?

Comment: There seems to be a major disconnect going on here: The object appears to be to validate fields in a (large) form filled out by end-users. It is extremely unusual for all fields on such a form to be mandatory. It is extremely usual to do other validations such as what type should it be (integer, money, percentage, text, boolean, etc), valid range or list of allowable values, etc at the same time. None of this is usually considered in terms of validation of a function's arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the questions.  Please see the "Additional Answers" section and let me know if it still doesn't add up.

Comment: -1:  There's a lot of words, but no clear problem here.  "Validate" is something Python does internally; it raises exceptions in all cases for all bad data.  There's no need to write additional code to do this.  "The list should contain the complete set of descriptions for all parameters" can be in the docstring.  There doesn't seem to be any actual problem here.  Just an urge to write extra code to raise an exception and report the doc string.  It would be helpful to show how Python's ordinary data type checking and exceptions are not working correctly.

Comment: It adds up to a hotchpotch. You appear to be saving your user input in individually-named variables, then your self-answer uses `eval` -- this is yuck ** 2. What's wrong with working with a dictionary that maps parameter names to user-input values?

Comment: @S.Lott: As I'm trying to point out, the OP's basic problem is to validate user input. However he has evidently stored his user input in individually-named variables, and transposed the problem into validating that all args of a function call have non-falsy values. Also re-read the heavily-amended question ... He no longer wants to return the whole function docstring anyway; he wants (sensibly) to return a message for each erroneous arg (properly: user form field).

Comment: @JohnMachin, could you elaborate on "What's wrong with working with a dictionary that maps parameter names to user-input values?"?  I believe the problem is that when that map is passed to the function, the function has no namespace access to the variables themselves -- if it's just a map of names to descriptions.

Comment: @S.Lott, no need for concern, there is nothing wrong with Python's validation.  Yes, I have an urge to write more code -- so that I might avoid writing the same repetitive code many times.  The reason is explained in the 2nd paragraph.  We seem to have different definitions for "validate".  The validation I need is explained in list item #1 of the summary (this is really getting long, I apologize everyone).

Comment: @Foo: Two different mappings: (1) using individually-named variables to store user input is NOT a good idea; you should store it as a dict mapping field names to field values (2) you need to define a map of names to descriptions (or error messages) once for each form. If you really don't like using `user_data['last_name']` and would prefer a namespace approach, you could whack your data into a class instance so that you can use `user_data.last_name` in your code -- but do it after you have done *all* your validations which should be table-driven, not in ad-hoc code.

Comment: @S.Lott, thanks for the clarification.  I can put the user input into a dict as you described.  By nature of our platform, it arrives in individual variables (preprocessing).  I will give this a try.

Comment: @Foo: ""validate" means the parameter's value is not empty string or None".  You do not need to test this.  Period.  If the variable should not be empty, but somehow gets a `None` value, then Python's internal TypeError will -- eventually -- get raised.  It always happens.  Illegal data always raises an exception.  You write no code for "validation" because Python already does all of the necessary type checking for you.  A `None` value raises an ordinary exception.  Just that simple.  You catch the exception.  You report the error.  That's it.  No "Validation" is needed for this case.

Comment: @Foo:  To avoid a lot of pointless coding, please provide **concrete** **specific** examples of where Python's own internal TypeError doesn't do everything you need.  Please provide an example instead of writing a lot of "requirements".  Please show some code which is broken or doesn't work or is untestable.  Please provide an example of what's broken right now.

Comment: @Foo: Please explain """By nature of our platform""". Also """it arrives in individual variables""" ... individual variables in what namespace? And what does """(preprocessing)""" mean?

Comment: @S.Lott, I've provided an example using a TypeError and given two reasons why it doesn't work.  John, I have answered your questions about variables in the questions list.  Forgot to explain "preprocessing", but it's like a C preprocessor that munges the code before it runs.

Comment: """The variables are in the global namespace. We use code injection ...""" ... Help! My browser's been hijacked! I've been diverted to thedailywtf.com ...

Comment: @Foo: "Maybe this is possible with exceptions, but I don't know how right now.".  Perhaps that should be your question.  Close this question.  Ask how to handle (1) multiple exceptions in a single message and (2) how to get information form a function's docstring.  These will give you code that meets all your requirements with a great deal of simplicity.

Comment: @JohnMachin, if you'll provide some specific questions about what I wrote that you don't understand, I'll be happy to try and clear it up.  Please keep in mind it's not easy to explain a complex platform in a few sentences.

Comment: @JohnMachin, I guess my question is, "Why are you expressing your frustration by insulting what I wrote when I'm trying to get a question answered?"

Comment: @S.Lott, thanks I will consider doing that.  I'm looking at a few more possibilities, but if they don't work out I will take your advice.

Comment: @Foo: Using code injection to dump "variables" into the global namespace is just about the most mind-bogglingly awful way of going about building a system ... words failed me.

Comment: @JohnMachin, any better suggestions appreciated

Comment: @Foo: Already done. See comment above from two days ago.

Comment: @JohnMachin, if you simply mean to discourage using global variables and instead limit scope and use dictionaries, I'm with you.  I wondered if you had a better solution for using a preprocessor to inject data into code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I don't understand the question or how what you posted as your 'best solution' meets the requirements, but working just from:

> I have a function with many input parameters, and I need a function
>   that will return a list of parameter names (not values) for each
>   parameter whose value is '' or None

Here's an easy way to do what that line seems to ask for:

```
def validate_parameters(args):
    unset = []
    for k in args:
        if args[k] is None or args[k]=="":
            unset.append(k)
    return unset
```

and then just call validate_parameters from the *first* line of a function:

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    print "Unset:", validate_parameters(locals())

>>> foo(1, None, 3)
Unset: ['b']
>>> foo(1, None, "")
Unset: ['c', 'b']
```

If it wasn't for the Python 2.2 requirement you could do it all in a single line list comprehension. The important thing is that you have to call it from the very first line of the function to ensure that `locals()` only picks up parameters and not any other local variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I edited to show how it could be made to satisfy the "user readable" parameter description requirement, then I realized I removed this requirement to make the problem easier.  You satisfied the requirements as written at the time of your post.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not <del>Zoidberg</del> a decorator?

```
def argsnotempty(**requiredargs):

    def decorator(func):

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            code     = func.func_code
            argsreq  = code.co_argcount - 1
            argsrec  = len(args)
            posargs  = code.co_varnames[1:argsreq + 1]
            errs     = []

            # validate positional args
            for i, arg in enumerate(args):
                if i == len(posargs):
                    break
                # falsy but not False: 0, '', None, [], etc.
                if not (arg or arg is False):
                    argname = posargs[i]
                    if argname in requiredargs:
                        errs.append(argname + " (" + requiredargs[argname] + ")")

            # validate keyword args
            for argname, arg in kwargs.iteritems():
                if argname in requiredargs:
                    if not (arg or arg is False):
                        errs.append(argname + " (" + requiredargs[argname] + ")")

            # make sure all required args are present
            for argname in requiredargs:
                if argname not in kwargs and argname not in posargs:
                    errs.append(argname + " (" + requiredargs[argname] + ")")

            return func(errs, *args, **kwargs)

        wrapper.__name__, wrapper.__doc__ = func.__name__, func.__doc__

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

The decorator checks to make sure the specified arguments are not empty, then calls the wrapped function with the list of "friendly" argument names which are blank as the first argument.  It also tries to check keyword arguments.  Arguments that aren't specified to the decorator aren't checked.

Usage:

```
@argsnotempty(a="alpha", b="beta", g="gamma")
def foo(errs, a, b, g):
    print errs

foo(3.14, "blarney", None)    # prints "['g (gamma)']"
```

Here's an example of raising an exception if you don't get the values you need:

```
@argsnotempty(a="alpha", b="beta", g="gamma")
def bar(errs, a, b, g):
    if errs:
       raise ValueError("arguments " + ", ".join(errs) + " cannot be empty")

bar(0, None, "")
```

Of course, you could tweak the decorator to do this for you, instead of including boilerplate code in each function.

Edit: Fixed some buggage

Comment: didn't get the "Zoidberg" joke :(

Comment: [Why not Zoidberg?](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/futurama-zoidberg-why-not-zoidberg) Sorry, I *may* hang out on Reddit too much...

Comment: OP wants Python 2.2 compatibility. 2.2 doesn't do decorators.

Comment: I got the Zoidberg and appreciate it.  Yes, unfortunately the 2.2 compatibility gets us.  Will update the title to make this more clear.  Thanks for answering.

Comment: Ugh, sorry 'bout that. Oh well, perhaps someone else will find it useful.

Comment: No problem.  Despite it not working with 2.2 I'd upvote you for the solid answer, but I don't have those privileges yet.

Comment: If the sole problem is decorators (didn't check it), you can fix that easily. Decorators can be applied without special `@` syntax, just do `def f(...) {...}; f = decorator(args)(f)` instead of `@decorator(args) def f(...) {...}`.

Comment: I took the decorator-validator idea and went kind of crazy with it, turning it into a framework that can be used to do any kind of validation, type coercion, etc. on any or all arguments of a function. If I have some time this week I might clean it up and post it somewhere, just for fun.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

To check that all required parameters are being passed into your function, you could create a dictionary that maps all of the required parameters to None, and then copy and update that dictionary at the start of every method.

```
needed_params = {'one': None, 'two': None, 'three': None}

def my_func(**kwargs):
    params = needed_params.copy()
    params.update(kwargs)
    for key, value in params.iteritems():
        if not value:
            raise TypeError("You need to provide the argument %s" % key)
    result = do_stuff_here
    return result
```

As noted in the comments, it's probably not a great idea to return a "user-friendly" description. Instead, you'll probably want to raise an error if a parameter is missing. Then you'll be able to handle this error elsewhere in your UI.

Kindall suggests a decorator. Depending on how complicated you want the checking to be, I think you could get by with something a little simpler than his suggestion:

```
def check_needed_params(target):
    needed_params = {'one': None, 'two': None, 'three': ''}
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        params = needed_params.copy()
        params.update(kwargs)
        for key, value in params.iteritems():
            if not value:
                raise TypeError("You need to provide the argument '%s'" % key)
        return target(**params)
    return wrapper
```

You can use this to identify functions that need to have their parameters checked like so:

```
@check_needed_params
def adder(**kwargs):
    return kwargs["one"] + kwargs["two"] + kwargs["three"]
```

Then, when this function is called, it will work seamlessly if you provide all the results, but will raise an error if you don't.

```
>>> adder(one=1, two=2, three=3)
6
>>> adder(one=1, two=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:/Users/.../python-6940fCr.py", line 8, in wrapper
TypeError: You need to provide the argument three
```

Comment: You don't need the `copy` module to make a shallow copy of a dict.

Comment: OP wants Python 2.2 compatibility. 2.2 doesn't do decorators.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is clever.  Unfortunately copy doesn't seem to be in Python 2.2, which is one of the conditions I need.  I thought about trying to replicate this without copy, but then I'd have to pass in more than one object to the method.  Also, I really do need to include the parameter descriptions and I don't see a way to do this.  Perhaps I could leave those in a hash outside the function and handle it that way.  If I'm missing something in your solution, please let me know!

Comment: But my original suggestion should work under 2.2. Although, honestly, I can't see why you would still need 2.2. Fedora hasn't shipped with 2.2 since yarrow, and Debian hasn't shipped with below 2.3 since woody.

Comment: The extra complexity in my decorator is to deal with the positional arguments (nicer for writing the function *and* for calling it) and for dealing with the "friendly" names requested by Foo. It does simplify things a lot if you only have to deal with kwargs, though!

Comment: Dictionaries should have a `copy` method in 2.2 if I'm not mistaken. As for parameter descriptions, I'm not sure why exactly you need them still. I think raising an exception (possibly one that you've created) is still the best call here, like S.Lott suggested. If you have more details as to why exactly you need to do it differently, and show something you've tried, I'd be more than happy to revise my answer.

Comment: Answer revised with example.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common "lots of variables" pattern.

```
def function( variable1, variable2, variable3, ..., variablen ):
   """user-friendly description of the function.
   :param variable1: meaning, units, range, whatever.
   :param variable2: meaning, units, range, whatever.
   ...
   :param variablen: meaning, units, range, whatever.
   :returns: range, type, whatever.
   """
   # do the processing
```

Do NOT check for missing or invalid parameters.  Python already does all the type checking ever needed.  Just write your code.  Do nothing special or extra to "validate" the inputs.
When exceptions arise, that means the inputs were bad.

It's just that simple.

Don't make it more complex by rewriting all of Python's type checking in extraneous if-statements.

Also.

NEVER mix "error returns" with valid returns.  Any kind of bad input **must** lead to an exception.  Good inputs return good values.  Bad inputs raise exceptions.

It's just that simple.  Don't make it more complex.

When calling this function, you can do this:

```
the_variables = { 
    'variable1': some value,
    'variable2': some value,
    ...
    'variablen': some value,
}
try:
    function( **the_variables )
except Exception:
    print( function.__doc__ )
```

Anything missing?  You get a `TypeError`.  Anything incorrectly `None` or empty?  You get a ValueError (or a TypeError, it depends).

When something goes wrong, you print the user-friendly description of the function.

This works pretty well and doesn't require very much programming at all.

Comment: I get the concept of throwing exceptions and printing doc strings.  It's the "do the processing" part and the complex requirements I have that make this hard.  Have updated the question to try and explain better.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: "do the processing" means just do the processing.  There's no "complexity" to this.  Simply write the simplest code to do the actual work.  "Validation" isn't necessary, since invalid data will throw exceptions, without fail.

Comment: The requirement is not to throw exceptions, but rather to report the entire list of parameter descriptions that are empty.  This solution would throw a single exception and print the function's doc string.  I know how to throw an exception because of an empty parameter.  Am updating the question again to be clearer.

Comment: @Foo: "report the entire list of parameter descriptions that are empty"?  Do you mean all parameter **values** which are missing or invalid?   If so, you may want to change the terminology you're using.

Comment: The problem isn't one of type validation, it's providing meaningful error messages to users when something goes wrong.  If you recommend not checking parameters for empty or None, then we must agree to disagree.  I always validate parameters in a public function.  I believe in catching errors as soon as they're detectable and providing useful error messages.  Allowing execution to continue makes debugging harder and is unsafe.  If you were not suggesting this, I misunderstood you.

Comment: @Foo: Python already does all the validation you'll ever need.  Catching errors "early" is a terrible mistake because -- at best -- you **duplicate** Python's own internal checking.  At worst you introduce new errors by incorrectly attempting a type check.  Useful error messages are **exactly** what exceptions are for.  "Allowing execution to continue" doesn't happen.  The exception is raised and the outer script or program which called your function must now cope with the fact that it provided bad data.  It can -- for example -- display the docstring.

Comment: @Foo: Please stop talking hypothetically and provide a specific, concrete example where Python's internal type error is not working for you.  Please provide real code that really makes some kind of mistake because an exception was not raised properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your function sounds quite large. Have you considered if it's appropriate to break it up or possibly turning it into a separate class?

Comment: As I'd originally written it, the function was less than 10 lines, but there was the empty string key bug.  Because I'd gotten most of the way there with a function, I assumed it was possible to finish with one.  I'd be fine with a class if that's what it takes and have updated the title to reflect this.

Comment: If it was 10 lines originally, it may not make sense to break out. Just thought I'd put it out there.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best answer I could come up with.  It requires doing a lot of prep work before calling the function, so I don't like it.  However, it meets all the requirements.

Thanks to everyone who participated, and I apologize that the question needed so many amendments!

```
def validate_parameters(params_map):
    """
    map is like {foo: "this is foo"}
    """
    missing_params_info = []
    for k,v in params_map.items():
        if not v:
            missing_params_info.append(k)
    return missing_params_info
# or do this if you want to use exceptions:
#    if missing_params_info:
#        raise TypeError('These parameters were unset: %s' % missing_params_info)

params = {}
params['foo'] = '1'
params['bar'] = '2'
params['empty'] = ''
params['empty2'] = ''
params['None'] = None

reverse_params_map = {
    'this is foo' : params['foo'],
    'this is bar' : params['bar'],
    'this is empty' : params['empty'],
    'this is empty2' : params['empty2'],
    'this is None' : params['None'],
}

print validate_parameters(reverse_params_map)

bash-3.00# python /var/tmp/ck.py
['this is empty2', 'this is empty', 'this is None']
```

Comment: -1: the comment `map is like {foo: "this is foo"}` is contradicted by the code which uses the `reverse_params_map` that has `{'this is foo':'1'}`.  Pretty well incomprehensible how this "solves" the problem.  It seems to merely add a layer of useless complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The question remains very confusing.  Very.

It could be that you're asking about introspection into the function's code object:

```
def noisy_typerror( func ):
    def fix_exception( **kw ):
        try:
            # This is generally needless; mostly a waste of CPU cycles.
            if not all(kw[arg] for arg in kw  ):
                raise TypeError
            # Simply apply the function and see if a TypeError occurs 
            return func( **kw )
        except TypeError:
            required= ", ".join( func.func_code.co_varnames[:func.func_code.co_argcount] )
            provided= ", ".join( "{0}={1!r}".format(k,v) for k,v in kw.items() )
            raise TypeError( "{2}( {0} ) got {1}".format(required, provided,func.func_name) )
    return fix_exception

@noisy_typerror
def some_func( this, that, the_other ):
    a= this
    b= that
    print( this, that, the_other )
```

To apply decorators in older version of Python

```
def the_real_func( this, that, the_other ):
   etc.

some_func= noisy_typerror( the_real_func )
```

Here are some use cases for this decorator

```
try:
    some_func( this=2, that=3 )
except TypeError, e:
    print e 
try:
    some_func( this=4 )
except TypeError, e:
    print e 
try:
    some_func( this=2, that=3, the_other='' )
except TypeError, e:
    print e
```

I get these kinds of results from printing the TypeError strings.

```
some_func( this, that, the_other ) got this=2, that=3
some_func( this, that, the_other ) got this=4
some_func( this, that, the_other ) got this=2, the_other='', that=3
```

Comment: This seems to do what I need.  It runs great on 2.6.4 but not on 2.2.  Do you have any specific questions I could answer to help make the question less confusing?  Thanks.

Comment: "not on 2.2"?  Can you possibly be specific on what this could mean?  I asked perhaps a half-dozen specific questions, all of which got rude and dismissive answers.  I see no point in asking them all again.  The answer you provided has a contradiction and -- what's important here -- no sensible use case.  How would anyone use the example you provided?  There's no meaningful context.  No actual problem.  And no reason to write any of this code.  However, it appears to amount to "TypeError doesn't provide enough information"

Comment: I apologize for coming across rude and dismissive.  I appreciate the input you've contributed.  It has helped.  On the question of Python 2.2 compatibility, there are a few things that prevent the above answer from working.  The first is decorators, the second is the print_function import.  They are not supported on 2.2.  When I run with this version I get errors that I don't get on 2.6.4.

Comment: You should be able to fix the `print_function` issues without too much help.  Remove the import.  Use the `print` statement.  The decorator issue is more subtle, since it requires replacing the decorator with an actual function call.

Comment: Example: "I have a function with many input parameters, and I need a function that will return a list of parameter names (not values) for each parameter whose value is '' or None".  It appears that you simply want to know **all** the parameters that don't pass some validation suite.  That appears to be all you want.  To know **all** invalid argument values instead of the Python default of one invalid argument value.  The entire rest of the question and comments appear to be  mostly misguided confusion.